# ControlTemplate with multiple content presenters. How to bind the Content of a ContentPresenter to the value of a DataTemplate in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a custom control Xamarin Forms that looks like this one:

```
public class CardView : Frame
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderDataTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create("HeaderDataTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(HeaderCardView), null, BindingMode.TwoWay);
    public static readonly BindableProperty BodyDataTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create("BodyDataTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(HeaderCardView));

    public DataTemplate HeaderDataTemplate
    {
        get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(HeaderDataTemplateProperty);
        set => SetValue(HeaderDataTemplateProperty, value);
    }

    public DataTemplate BodyDataTemplate
    {
        get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(BodyDataTemplateProperty);
        set => SetValue(BodyDataTemplateProperty, value);
    }

    public CardView()
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform.Equals("iOS"))
        {
            HasShadow = false;
            OutlineColor = Color.Transparent;
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to create a "card" control that can define 2 DataTemplates for a Heading and a Body.

So I define a ControlTemplate that use 2 content presenters:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderCardControlTemplate">
    <StackLayout>
        <ContentView Padding="5" BackgroundColor="#a6192e">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Parent.HeaderDataTemplate, Mode=TwoWay}"></ContentPresenter>
        </ContentView>
        <ContentView>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Parent.BodyDataTemplate}"></ContentPresenter>
        </ContentView>
     </StackLayout>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And use it like this:

```
<controls:HeaderCardView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderCardControlTemplate}">                                        
    <controls:HeaderCardView.HeaderDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Value}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
                <Label FontAttributes="Bold, Italic" Text="{Binding Type}" HorizontalOptions="End" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></Label>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>                                    
    </controls:HeaderCardView.HeaderDataTemplate>
</controls:HeaderCardView>
```

However the ContentPresenter is not showing the HeaderDataTemplate that suppose to be the Grid.

Any ideas of what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Hey were you be able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Hi @RodrigoJuarez i remember I had to do some manual sets using the BindingPropertyChangeDelegate pram from the BindableProperty.
When the data template change I create a new View and set it manually internally.